# ROS2 Resolve topic names rclcpp

Tags: ros, rclcpp, remapping, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ros1 cpp I was able to resolve a string containing the topic name to the actual topic name that accounts for remappings using the following block:

```
  // Determine topic name (including remapping)
  std::string mag_topic_name = "/imu/mag";
  mag_topic_name = ros::names::resolve(mag_topic_name);
```

Is there a similar way I can do this in `rclcpp` ROS2? I tried digging through the documentations, but could not find something.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371697/ros2-resolve-topic-names-rclcpp/) by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 291 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking for this today, and there is a function in Galactic Rolling:

```
RCLCPP_PUBLIC std::string resolve_topic_name(const std::string & name, bool only_expand = false) const override;
```

See [this pull request](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1410). I've copied the code over to my own node.

The `only_expand` parameter, if `true`, just adds on the namespace. If `false`, it also applies remapping, which is probably the option you want.

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2021-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2